# Android service in C?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to run an executable written in C and have it communicate with Activity via a Unix Domain Socket. I want it to keep running reliably even when the app isn't on screen - which requires setting up a foreground service.

[Android's guide on services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) however it seems only mentions either services running in the main or separate thread, but same process, and obviously always in java. So how do I then run a different executable and have Android NOT kill it, like a normal OS?

Comment: A foreground service is more reliable, but it can still be killed by the OS.  There is no way on Android to reliably have a service, or any other code, run forever.  If you explain what the app does we might be able to suggest a better way to architect it that doesn't need that, but there is no way to prevent the OS from killing any service at will.

Comment: Also you have a few things wrong-  Services don't run in any thread.  The lifecycle methods of a Service run on the main thread, but a Service itself has no worker and does no work.  You have to set that up yourself if you want it (you can do work in onStartCommand, or launch a thread from there).  And you don't really run separate executables in Android.   Although you can run C in an Android app via JNI, or even write an app entirely in C via the NDK.

Comment: "I want to run an executable written in C... I want it to keep running reliably even when the app isn't on screen" -- root the device and modify something like `init.rc`. Better yet, include your custom code in a custom firmware build that you deploy to bespoke hardware.